# Is "reduce" transitive or intransitive?

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Is the verb *reduce* used incorrectly in the sentence below? Would you personally choose to replace *reduce* with an alternative such as *drop* or *fall*?

> The birth rate has **reduced** over the past 10 years.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with *decreased*, but *fallen* isn't wrong, and *dropped* might be used if the fall was precipitous and it was your intention to point that out.

Comment: *Oh dear, I see you have reduced since we met last! Been dieting?*

Comment: v.intr. 1. To become diminished. 2. To lose weight, as by dieting.
3. Biology To undergo meiosis. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reduce

Comment: Some EFL books say reduced should only be used with object, along with raise (rise being commonly contrasted with raised as verbs which are "often confused"). That's what prompted the question. To my ear it doesn't sound ideal in the above sentence. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 2):

*[Reduce](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/reduce)* may be used as a transitive or intransitive verb.

> The birth rate has reduced/dropped/fallen over the past ten years

are all correct. Here *reduce* is used intransitively.

> He reduced the number of mistakes from ten to five.

Here *reduce* is used transitively.

Comment: How is it used in that phrase, intransitively? If so, can you add an example of a transitive usage?

Comment: This is [general reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reduce).

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in England, spent my 20s and 30s in Belgium and the Netherlands and have lived in the USA for the last 20 years.

I don't recall hearing the intransitive use of "reduce" in England when I was growing up, but I notice it now when I return there each year. It sounds horrible to me. I would use "decrease" or "fall" instead.

I never hear the intransitive use of "reduce" in the US.

I would also point out that the French verb "reduire" -- presumably the source of reduce in English -- is a transitive verb.

Let's kill off "reduce" as a transitive verb!

Comment: As an American, I can't recall ever hearing someone using "reduce" as an intransitive verb.